# access sqlite database results to populate view

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a database class with this method:

```
public Cursor getQuoteById(int qid)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM quotes a LEFT JOIN authors b ON b.author_id=a.quote_author WHERE a.quote_id = ?";
    Cursor results = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{String.valueOf(qid)});
    return results;
}
```

In my activity, all I want is to use the results to populate view elements. i have this:

```
    Qdb = new DbHelper(this);
    Cursor results = Qdb.getQuoteById(Integer.parseInt(id));
    authorname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.share_author_name);
    authorname.setText(results.getString(results.getColumnIndex("first_name")));
```

I get an error:

> android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Can anyone please point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call [`moveToFirst()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst()) before accessing its data and also check the return value in case of an empty result.

```
// e.g.
if(!cursor.moveToFirst())
    return;
// now access the data
```

By default, after the query returns, the position will be at `-1`, before the first data set.